# Set Production on ng build in angular 4

Tags: angular

I want my API Endpoint URL to point to production on running

```
ng build
```

how can this be achieved in angular 4 ?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Where is your starting point?

Comment: my starting point is ng build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use '--prod' with ng build. Adding this actually does a lot of things such as reducing code size using tree shaking,switching environment configurations etc.You can refer to official documentation for details.

If you are referring to changing like property file,well you can use environment.ts file. Ng build without prod flag takes values from environment.ts file and with prod flag takes values from environment.prod.ts file.

Comment: thats not a prob. i want a particular code to run and change the global endpoint on running ng buils

Comment: If you are referring to changing like property file,well you can use environment.ts file. Ng build without prod flag takes values from environment.ts file and with prod flag takes values from environment.prod.ts file.

Comment: @Apoorv If it helped you, please upvote and mark it as answer. Cheers!